# JS in web scraping via Excel VBA

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, bundle

Can anyone help me with this?

I want to do a web scraping via Excel VBA, and the target website has some js bundle code there. See the screenshot below.

But, interestingly, I can only get the green part of web text to the spreadsheet, any suggestions and advice on how to get the red part of web HTML codes, please.

Thanks in advance

Lei
[image]

[image]

```
    Private Declare Function DeleteUrlCacheEntry Lib "Wininet.dll" Alias "DeleteUrlCacheEntryA" (ByVal lpszUrlName As String) As Long

Public Sub ConnectDB()
'Get data for world indices

  Dim strUrl$, strWeb$, strLne$, j&
  Dim strArray() As String  'Save web text split to lines
  Dim strDrray() As String  'Save data string to lines
  
  With DAT: On Error GoTo EndSub
  
  '1.GetWebString - indices; split web text to lines (strArray)
    strUrl = "https://ct.icmarkets.com/copy/strategy/xxxxx/"
    
    DeleteUrlCacheEntry strUrl:
    With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp"):
      .Open "get", strUrl, False, "Delphima@hotmail.com,", "xxxxxxx":
      .send: strWeb = .responseText:
    End With
    
    strArray = Split(strWeb, Chr(10))
    
  '2.Write WebText to Excel rows
    For j = LBound(strArray) To UBound(strArray)
      strLne = Trim(strArray(j))
      Cells(j + 1, 1) = strLne
    Next
  End With

EndSub:End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Please do not post image of your code, edit your question and include your code in codeblock.

Comment: The code block, drive me mad...  VBA code seems not well supported.  Sorry.

Comment: Indent the entire code again in the editor then copy&paste in, it should format properly.

Comment: Can you check if `<div id="root">` exist in `responsetext`? Normally we will declare a `HTMLDocument` and assign `responsetext` like so: `htmldoc.body.innerhtml = .responsetext`. From there you can use method like `GetElementByID` to target a specific node you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks!     <div id="root"> is not there.     I'm not very well knowledgeable about GetElementByID, could you share some code examples, please?

Comment: You need to check the Network traffic and find out which request is loading the bit of HTML you require - you probably need to emulate a few "GET" / "POST" requests to get the full HTML you see in the browser window. I.e when you send a request to `"https://ct.icmarkets.com/copy/strategy/xxxxx/"` there'll be more than one response! Either that or you need to recreate the JS that is formulating the HTML.

Comment: @Zhou without being able to check the website, it's possible that the portion you want is generated dynamically. Check the Network tab and see if the request you are sending is similar to the browser's.

Comment: @Wu  , Jam .  Thanks, guys. I've put the ending of responses to the request. I researched weeks ago, some HTML code behind js bundle was not sent to vba.  But I don't know how to coding and knock js gate to open it.

Comment: @Zhou Example of `GetElementById` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54509641/using-getelementbyid-vba-webscraping

Comment: @wu  my code return .responseText  totally has not included the red part of HTML in web inspection image.

Comment: @Zhou is there some specific info you are looking for within the red part? Sometimes the data are stored in a different format and came via other XHR requests. You might need to look in the Network traffic harder. If all else fails, you might want to consider `InternetExplorer` method of scrapping

Comment: @wu,  All the data I need is in the hidden part.     InternetExplorer method that's a possible solution.  But I don't have knowledge of it.   Any suggestion? esp. work with js together.

Comment: Theres plenty of examples, just google internetexplorer vba scrapping should give you plenty of resources. Post a new question if you ran into any issue. It looks like you need to login so most likely you will start the scrapping from the login page

Comment: @Wu  OK, thanks a lot. I will have a look now.

Comment: @Wu  IE can't open js part as well.  There must be some part of IE setting affect get the content of js.

Comment: the word is _**scraping**_